# Android Jetpack security - sample code won't compile "no suitable constructor found for FileReader(EncryptedFile)"

Tags: android, android-jetpack-security

I'm working on testing the beta version of Google's Android Jetpack for security.

The sample code [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data#java) is simple enough, but it will not compile:

```
foo.java:274: error: no suitable constructor found for FileReader(EncryptedFile)
             new BufferedReader(new FileReader(encryptedFile))) {
```

I have included the dependency in my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-rc01"
}
```

Searching the FileReader documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileReader) I don't see how to get this sample code working.

For completeness, here is my function:

```
259   void jetpackTest()
260   {
261     KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC;
262     String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(keyGenParameterSpec);
263     
264     String fileToRead = "my_sensitive_data.txt";
265     EncryptedFile encryptedFile = new EncryptedFile.Builder(
266             new File("private", fileToRead),
267             this,
268             masterKeyAlias,
269             EncryptedFile.FileEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM_HKDF_4KB
270     ).build();
271 
272     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
273     try (BufferedReader reader =
274                  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(encryptedFile))) {
275 
276         String line = reader.readLine();
277         while (line != null) {
278             stringBuffer.append(line).append('\n');
279             line = reader.readLine();
280         }
281     } catch (IOException e) {
282         // Error occurred opening raw file for reading.
283     } finally {
284         String contents = stringBuffer.toString();
285     }
286   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kotlin version also have some error, I think there has been a mistake or a typo.

Based on the code for writing files in the sample code, can you try as:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(encryptedFile.openFileInput()))
```